# Import Oracle CRM OD to SQL Table via SSIS (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, crm

Has anyone been able to consume data from Oracle CRM On-Demand (Service Request data) and into a table through SQL Server 2008 SSIS? Loading the WSDL file does not seem to work for me. It appears, that a custom script is needed to consume CRM OD data.